# call javascript if validation fails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem. I need to call javascript function when form validation fails.
I am trying to do this. Here is my create action in  comment_controller.

```
  def create
    p params
    @comment = parent.comments.build(params[:comment].merge(:ip => request.remote_ip))
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @page.url, :notice => "grats"
    else
      @country = @page.country
      @city = @page.city
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :template => "pages/show" }
        format.js { render "pages/show" }
      end
    end
  end
```

and pages/show.js.erb have code

```
$('.main').fadeOut(5000);
```

but it doesn't work. I have tried another js code, but it didn't work too.  What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What was the other js code you where trying?

the most simple thing should be like:

```
alert("foo");
```

Does an html element with class 'main' exist at all? (Look at your source code)

Does your response actually render the show.js.erb file? Your server log would tell you.

```
Rendered portal/cart_items/update.js.erb (38.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 650ms (Views: 51.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
```

The first line is typical for an ajax response.

And FireBug would help you to see what happens on the server side.

Comment: i have an element with class main.
'alert("foo");' doesn't work too(

Comment: So most likely you don't render the js. What's you production.log saying (either look at log/production.log or the server output in the terminal? Sure you call this as ajax? How does your link or js look that actually makes the request?

Comment: it have Rendered pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application only. I don't know why it doesn't have show.js.erb

Comment: i didn't understand your last question. I wrote everything what in my js file, and i am trying to call this js with render

Comment: Ok, I understand now. You do a simple form post. In this case you can't send back js (that's for ajax requests) like you try. Don't know what exactly you want to do, but most likely you would have to make quite some changes to your code to get it work. To start with you would have to render your form with ':remote => true'. But this would require several additional changes.

Comment: i am rendering page that I try adding the comment. and I want to show error messages on it with using jquery notification plugin. So i need to use javascript. I will try to know more about "remote => true"

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to redirect to the page that you try adding the comment to?

if so, try

```
else
  @country = @page.country
  @city = @page.city
  flash[:errors] = "Your error message..."
  redirect_to @page
end
```

Although I recommend to do a basic validation in javascript on client-side before which makes displaying the errors easier.

Comment: i am rendering page that I try adding the comment. and I want to show error messages on it with using jquery notification plugin. So i need to use javascript. But i don't know how